# C++ Inheritence: Passing Data to Base

Tags: c++, inheritance

Need some help with a school project on inheritance. The hierarchy is as follows:
[Shape] <- [Quadrilateral] <- [GenRectangle]

GenRectangle has a constructor that accepts a Color object (using a Color.H)

```
GenRectangle(GenPoint ul, GenPoint lr, Color c)
```

I am unsure how to get Color c to pass all the way to Shape using the methods given. I was thinking about using something like:

```
GenRectangle::GenRectangle(GenPoint ul, GenPoint lr, Color c) : Quadrilateral(___, ___, ___, ___, c)
```

But I don't know what to put in the blanks. pretty sure that is a dead end though. My teacher doesn't typically answer emails over the weekend so I'm stuck trying to figure it out on my own. My notes show me things like my attempt above but only for one level of inheritance, not three. Here the .H files I have to use:

GenRectangle.h

```
class GenRectangle: public Quadrilateral
{

  public:
    GenRectangle();
    GenRectangle(GenPoint ul, GenPoint lr, Color c);
    void setPoints(GenPoint ul, GenPoint lr);
    double getArea();
    void print();
};
```

Quadrilateral.h

```
class Quadrilateral : public Shape
{
  protected:

    GenPoint a;
    GenPoint b;
    GenPoint c;
    GenPoint d;


  public:
    Quadrilateral();
    Quadrilateral(GenPoint a, GenPoint b, GenPoint c, GenPoint d, Color color);
    void setPoints(GenPoint a, GenPoint b, GenPoint c, GenPoint d);
    double getPerimeter();
    void print();
    void draw();
};
```

Shape.h

```
class Shape
{
  protected:
    Color color;

  public:
    Shape();
    Color getColor();
    void setColor(Color color);
    virtual double getPerimeter() = 0;
    virtual void print()= 0;
    virtual void draw() = 0;

};
```

Edit:
Also, should I pass the datafields from GenRectangle to Quadrilateral with or without attempting to set GenRectangles inherited datafields?

This:

```
GenRectangle::GenRectangle(GenPoint ul, GenPoint lr, Color c) : Quadrilateral(ul, GenPoint(lr.x,ul.y) , lr, GenPoint(u1.x, lr.y), c)
{
    this->a.setPoint(ul.getX(), ul.getY());
    this->b.setPoint(lr.getX(), ul.getY());
    this->c.setPoint(lr.getX(), lr.getY());
    this->d.setPoint(ul.getX(), lr.getY());


}
```

or This:

```
GenRectangle::GenRectangle(GenPoint ul, GenPoint lr, Color c) : Quadrilateral(ul, GenPoint(lr.x,ul.y) , lr, GenPoint(u1.x, lr.y), c)
{

}
```

Comment: Are you saying that, given two vertices of a rectangle (axis-aligned?) you don't know how to obtain the other two vertices?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have problems with calling a base constructor (I think you can do it) or simple math?

Is

```
GenRectangle::GenRectangle(GenPoint ul, GenPoint lr, Color c) : Quadrilateral(ul, GenPoint(lr.x, ul.y), lr, GenPoint(u1.x, lr.y) c)
```

an answer?

Answer (score 0):

This seems a geometry question.

A quadrilateral is defined by four points that are its vertices. A rectangle by two points owing to its symmetry and its sides are parallel or perpendicular to axes.

```
 (p1)------------(p4)
  |               |
  |               |
 (p2)------------(p3)
```

I think you have given p1 and p3 input in `GenRectangle`.

To obtain p2 and p4, use following formula.

```
p2.x = p1.x
p2.y = p3.y

p4.x = p3.x
p4.y = p1.y
```

Using this relationship, you should be able to get other two points (p2 and p4) to be passed in quadrilateral. I hope their order does matter. So, take care of it.

In your case

```
GenRectangle::GenRectangle(GenPoint ul, GenPoint lr, Color c) : Quadrilateral(ul, GenPoint(ul.x, lr.y), GenPoint(lr.x,ul.y), lr, c)
```

You can take care of order.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the coordinates to create the shape, I just didn't know how to pass the points to the base class.  I knew they each had to be a GenPoint, but I did not know I could use GenPoint(ul.x, lr.y) to pass those seperate x's and y's. Once I test this I will accept your answer.

Comment: Also. Since GenRectangle doesn't have any datafields, should I use the constructors to set it's inherited datafields, or just pass them to the parent object (in this case, Quadrilateral). Edit made at end of question to clarify.

Comment: In my opinion, second option will be better. In the first case, problem is that in future due to some maintenance, name of data members may change or some may get removed. So, first one will break. Second will work as long as the behaviour of constructor function remains same.